# scipy.interp2d warning and large errors off the grid

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a 2-dimensional function and I am running into what I consider weird behavior by scipy.interpolate.interp2d. I don't understand what the problem is, and I'd be happy for any help or hints.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(20)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing = 'ij')
val = xx + yy
f = interp2d(xx, yy, val, kind = 'linear')
```

When I run this code, I get the following Warning:

> scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py:981: RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be
>   added because the number of B-spline coefficients already exceeds the
>   number of data points m. Probable causes: either s or m too small.
>   (fp>s)    kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=18,15 m=200 fp=0.000000 s=0.000000
>   warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))

I don't understand why interp2d would use any splines when I tell it it should do linear interpolation. When I continue and evaluate f on the grid everything is good:

```
>>> f(1,1)
array([ 2.])
```

When I evaluate it off the grid, I get large errors, even though the function is clearly linear.

```
>>> f(1.1,1)
array([ 2.44361975])
```

I am a bit confused and I am not sure what the problem is. Did anybody run into similar problems? I used to work with matlab and this is almost 1:1 how I would do it there, but maybe I did something wrong.

When I use a rectangular grid (i.e. y = np.arange(10)) everything works fine by the way, but that isn't what I need. When I use cubic instead of linear interpolation, the error gets smaller (that doesn't make much sense either since the function is linear) but is still unacceptably large.

Comment: It's docs say: `This class returns a function whose call method uses
    spline interpolation to find the value of new points.`  Poor extrapolation is characteristic of spline interpolation. They also make recommendations for regular grid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my understanding a linear spline is just piecewise linear interpolation, or am I wrong there? I don't extrapolate,  (1.1,1) is in the range of the data. And my grid is regular, isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried: `ff=interpolate.interp2d(y,x,xx+yy,kind='linear')`? (check the docs regarding row/column coordinates).

Comment: This `interp2d` uses: `interpolate.bisplrep(...., kx=1, ky=1)`, that is a 'a bivariate B-spline representation of a surface'.  This is not the same as a bunch of piecewise linear planes.  There is a MATLAB b-spline that probably behaves the same (and may have more documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a couple of things and managed to get (kind of) what I want using scipy.LinearNDInterpolator. However, I have to convert the grid to lists of points and values. Since the rest of my program stores coordinates and values in grid format that is kind of annoying, so if possible I'd still like to get the original code to work properly.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(20)
coords = list(itertools.product(x,y))
val = [sum(c) for c in coords]
f = LinearNDInterpolator(coords, val)

>>>f(1,1)
array(2.0)

>>> f(1.1,1)
array(2.1)
```

Comment: Reshaping the grid to points isn't that difficult.  You could make `points=np.column_stack([xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()])` and `val=(xx+yy).ravel()`.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful, I'll go with this option then. It would still be interesting to know why interp2d does so poorly at interpolating a linear function.

Comment: `LinearNDIterpolator` use Qhull to triangulate the surface, and does linear interpolation with the appropriate triangular plane.  It is close to the MATLAB interp2d linear.